# Disconnect from samba share

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

Sometimes during the same Windows (Vista) session i have to connect to the same (samba) file server in a workgroup (no domain) as another user. It seems Windows has cached the current connection with user info.
To force a new authentification i run a batch script:

```
@echo off
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
```

But this sometime works and sometimes doesn't and force me to close the Windows session.

Is there a way to completely disconnect from actual shares to login as a new user.

**Update**

I have no program open, no drive letter connected and "net use" empty but still the IPC$ share open on the samba server (smbstatus).

Now adding

```
net use \\server\IPC$
```

and again

```
net use * /delete /y
```

And "net use" complains about open files or **searches in folders** with \server\IPC$ (message in spanish).

I think Vista is still holding the share for searching and indexing.

**Update 2**

I think i get this now: i stopped "Windows Search" service and after running the batch i get asked again for credentials.

Comment: Except now you get no indexing.  Adding a netbios alias is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: On Windows 7 indexing is optional on a per-drive and even per-directory tree basis, I'm sure there must be similar settings for Vista.

Comment: Also note that cases where you've done something like open a file on that share can leave an application with a directory open, which will also prevent the share from completely going away.

Answer (score 5):

Right-clicking on the drive in My Computer and saying disconnect is the most reliable way that I've found.  Problems usually arise when you have a file on one of the shares held open by some process.

However, rather than disconnect when you need to access the shares as another user why don't you add a netbios alias to samba so you can use the shares with 2 different users simultaneously?

For example, if your server was named "servername" you could add this line in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
netbios aliases = altservername
```

Restart samba and you can then connect to \\altservername\share with a new user and windows won't care.  Connecting to the IP address would probably work too but this has always seemed easier to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop the "Workstation" service. This handles all SMB shares so restarting it will flush these connections.

1. As an Administrative user, open the Services panel (Start, type `services.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Search for Workstation in the list on the right.
3. Right-click Workstation, and click Restart. Wait for the progress bar to go through.

Comment: This is what I have to do on every WIn 10 device that I need to disconnect from SMB shares. `net use` is pmuch worthless in that regard. Really is a hassle for scripts...