# Disconnect from a network share

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, network-shares, connection

How do I *really* disconnect from a network share in Windows 8.1?

I'm familiar with using `net use` to disconnect from a network share, even if it isn't mapped to a network drive letter:

```
net use \\server\share /del
```

However, even after doing so, the folder may remain connected: if I quickly open Windows Explorer and go to \server\share, it connects immediately, without prompting me for a password, and I can do whatever file operations I want in that folder without it ever showing up again in `net use`'s output.

If I use `net use /del` then leave things alone for 10-15 seconds, then the share appears to really disconnect, so that Windows Explorer prompts for password and takes time to reconnect and so on.

I'm not sure that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/70095/4160); that makes it sound like `net use` sometimes fails, while my issue is that it appears to work but leaves connections open that it can't see.

Is there a way to really, truly close network share connections, besides `net use`? Is there a way to see what connections are open that `net use` isn't telling me about?

(This is using a Windows 8.1 Active Directory domain member as a client and a non-domain member Samba server.)

Comment: Well, with Windows 7: Remove the connections with `net use * /del` then restart the *Workstation* service (may have to close open Explorer windows and files on the share first). This will terminate everything. Also take a look at the *Credential Manager* in case you want to remove any stored credentials. Not sure how much of this applies to Windows 8.

Answer (score 9):

Run `net use * /delete` instead. This will remove all share connections, and force you to use a new username/password, unless you're on a domain joined computer

Comment: Also use `klist purge` from the other answer. I wasn't able to reconnect with a different user until I used this. Make sure to execute this as your user and *not* as Administrator.

Comment: This part of windows is horribly inconsistent, I'm connected to a network share and running this just shows `There are no entries in the list`

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like what you're running into is Kerberos credential caching, which refreshes on a timed interval.

Try this, which will disconnect the map, and then purge the Kerberos list:

```
net use \\server\share /del
klist purge
```

`klist` by itself should show you currently active Kerberos 'tickets', that may be used.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about `klist`, but doing `klist purge` didn't help. (My server is not a domain member, so Kerberos isn't involved, is it?"

Comment: Hmm... If you kill the map, and then immediately kill and restart Explorer.exe, does it clear the cached credentials?

Answer (score 2):

8 years later still same issues...

"Klist purge" and restarting the explorer service did not work in a few cases I've tried. A reboot has worked for me on many occasions but **restarting the workstation service** also did the trick

**Tip to Restart the workstation service:**

You may use hotkey Win+R and run **services.msc** look for "Workstation Service" and restart it (or stop and start it again)

Comment: Omg what a glitch. To automate in elevated PowerShell: Stop-Service LanmanWorkstation -Force; Start-Service LanmanWorkstation