# How to stop windows explorer from trying to log in to a network share so many times after a password change

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, network-shares, auto-login, share-credentials

So typically, I'm logged into at least one network share with my Windows 8.1 machine.  And every 30 days or so, I have to update my passwords on the network shares.  However, if I attempt to access one of those shares using internet explorer before and after the password change, it tries to log in with my old password so many times that I'm subseqently locked out of the network share.  To try and avoid this, I've told windows not to cache my network credentials.  But it seems to keep an in-memory cache of the last-used credentials during a windows log-in.

To avoid the problem right now, I have to close all Explorer windows, change the remote password, restart my local machine, and then re-attach the shares with the new password.

Is there an easier way, perhaps to tell windows not to re-try when a login to a network share fails, or to clear the in-memory cache of credentials?

There is some info here ([Disconnect from a network share](https://superuser.com/questions/806366)) about disconnecting from a share - that may be a better option than restarting my machine, but I was hoping for something other than a command-line command that I'd have to dig up and repeat once a month.

Comment: The better option is "use a Domain". ;)

Comment: I'd love to use a Domain, but the shares I'm mounting are accessed by VPN and managed by other organizations on other domains.

Comment: Yuck....  How exactly are you updating the passwords on all these disparate shares?

Comment: The disparate shares are on two remote domains, so I only have two passwords to update once a month (via the prompt when making a RDP connection), but getting locked out of either domain is very annoying, as I'm locked out of all the shares (and RDP) in the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the silence, I'm assuming the only way is to manually detach from the attached server, with the command:

```
net use * /delete /yes
```

Which detaches any mounted smb share.